# Column name not printing properly when using round function

Tags: pyspark

I am getting column name as `round(sum((quantity * unitprice)) AS 'invoice_value', 0)` instead of `invoice_value` when I am running below code in pyspark3.

```
summary_df1 = orders_df\
.groupBy("country", "invoiceno")\
.agg(expr("sum(quantity) as total_quantity"), round(expr("sum(quantity * unitprice) as invoice_value"))).sort("invoiceno")
```

tried different combinations but not working.

Comment: the column name should be at the end of all column operations. so, it should be after the `round` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one -

```
summary_df1 = orders_df
.groupBy("country", "invoiceno")
.agg(expr("sum(quantity) as total_quantity"), expr("round(sum(quantity * unitprice)) as invoice_value")).sort("invoiceno")
```